# Criar tooltips usando Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Criei um attribute customizado, chamado ToolTip. Gostaria de adicionar tooltips em toda propriedade que possua esse attribute.

**Exemplo:**

Em meu model tenho a seguinte propriedade:

```
[Required, ToolTip("Neste campo você deve inserir um nome.")]
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

E na view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Que renderiza:

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Nome é obrigatório." id="Nome" name="Nome" type="text" value="">
```

Eu gostaria que renderizasse com os atributos de tooltip do bootstrap, assim:

```
<input data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Neste campo você deve inserir um nome." class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Nome é obrigatório." id="Nome" name="Nome" type="text" value="">
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já viu esse link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707997/asp-net-mvc-extending-dataannotions

Comment: Como criou esse atributo?

Comment: @Jhonatan Eu queria mesmo era usar o TextBoxFor padrão, sem criar um helper novo ou extension, mas não estou certo se isso pode ser feito.

Comment: @Randrade idêntico ao da resposta escolhida no link do Jhonathan

Comment: @EduardoMoreira , acredito que sem nenhuma customização não seria possível, pelo menos não conheço.

Comment: @Jhonatan é, pelo visto não tem mesmo. como esse é um tópico um tanto avançado pra mim que estou iniciando eu acabei viajando na maionese. mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu diria que o ideal é você escrever sua própria extensão para gerar o `<input>`. [O fonte original pode ajudar](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs). Veja este método:

```
private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, object value, bool useViewData, bool isChecked, bool setId, bool isExplicitValue, string format, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    { ... }
```

Aí você poderia usar:

```
@Html.TextBoxWthTooltipFor(model => model.Nome, ...)
```

Comment: eu estava querendo continuar com o TextBoxFor padrão, devia ter explicado melhor lá na pergunta. mas pelo visto não tem mesmo como fazer sem dar uma customizada.

Comment: Sim, não tem como, mas você pode aproveitar este método que apontei e fazer o seu.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei indo por outro caminho. Percebi que conseguia colocar o tooltip em uma tag span ao invés de colocar no próprio elemento.

Ficou assim:

```
public static MvcToolTip ToolTipFor<TModel, TValue> (this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,  string placement = "right")
{
    var exp = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
    var attributes = exp.Expression.Type.GetProperty(exp.Member.Name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ToolTipAttribute), false);

    var message = (((ToolTipAttribute) attributes[0]).Description);

    return new MvcToolTip(htmlHelper.ViewContext, message, placement);
}

public class MvcToolTip : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TextWriter _writer;

    public MvcToolTip(ViewContext viewContext, string message, string placement = "right")
    {
        _writer = viewContext.Writer;

        _writer.Write("<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-original-title='" + message + "' data-placement='" + placement + "'>");

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _writer.Write("</span>");
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
@using (Html.ToolTipFor(m => m.Pessoa.Nome))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pessoa.Nome, new {@class = "form-control"})
}
<script> $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); </script>
```